# teststack white get the main window after the login window

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, white-framework

I am working on automating a windows application using Teststack white, the current issues that I have is that after logging in the main application, white doesn't seems to find the new window.

```
 var pathAp = appPath(path);
        Application application = Application.Launch(pathAp);
        Window window = application.GetWindow("login");
        TextBox userName = window.Get<TextBox>("userName");
        TextBox pass = window.Get<TextBox>("pass");
        userName.Enter("user1");
        pass.Enter("pass");
        Button login = window.Get<Button>("login");
        login.Click();
        //now the program will wait and the main window will show up
        Window mainWindow = application.GetWindow("main");
```

for some reason the program throws an error message saying that it can't find the window.
any ideas guys thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I figured out what happened after logging in to the application the new process ID appears instead of the old one, so I used the Application.Attach() method to get hold of the new "Application", the attach method takes a PID as parameter, to get that you can use the following method, Process.GetProcessesByName(), and you can then get the ID of the process that can eventually pass it to the attach method.

Comment: Could you post your new code of this if you still have it? Because i am having same issue and trying to figure this out.

Comment: var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Name of your app")[0];
           app = Application.Attach(process.Id);
           Window window2 = app.GetWindow("PROfit Version 4.4.24");

Comment: did you manage to do it the same way?, and I would like to ask you what kind of tool are you using for locating the UI elements?

Comment: a little bit diferently :) 
 TestStack.White.Application application1 = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(@"c:\path\app.exe");
                application1.Process.WaitForExit();
                
                TestStack.White.Application mainApplication = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("app");
Of course this method would go wrong if there would me more of the same app opened so before opening i kill all proceses with this aplication name. I have Visual UI application Verify tool.