# TestStack.White and CCleaner

Tags: c#, white-framework

I've very new to the TestStack (White) UI Automation library and I'm having a bit of an issue in terms of "hooking" the process. I'm trying to hook CCleaner, but I keep getting

> An unhandled exception of type 'TestStack.White.AutomationException'
>   occurred in TestStack.White.dll
>
> Additional information: Couldn't find window with title Piriform
>   CCleaner in process 1156, after waiting for 30 seconds:

My current code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.Factory;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
using TestStack.White.InputDevices;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;

namespace NightWipe
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ExeSourceFile = @"C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe";
        private static TestStack.White.Application _application;
        private static TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window _mainWindow;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clean();
        }

        public static string clean()
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExeSourceFile);
            _application = TestStack.White.Application.AttachOrLaunch(psi);

            _mainWindow = _application.GetWindow("Piriform CCleaner");
            _mainWindow.WaitWhileBusy();


            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that maybe it was the name of the process since CCleaner starts another process (not CCleaner.exe) but CCleaner64.exe as seen [here](http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/YvDvUyq.png), which I can assume is for 64 bit operating systems maybe? Anyway I tried names including: "CCleaner", "CCleaner64"; but this threw the same exact exception.

I'm using Inspect by Microsoft and this is what it pulls for me (large image):
 [Inspect's information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GphpR.png). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with "CCleaner starts another process" while White may not search for windows of child processes. Try to start CCleaner with `Process.Start` and check whether the PID of created process is equal to the PID of the process that owns the window you actually see. Also you may try to use UIAutomation methods, that White is based upon. You can try enumerate all root windows from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement(v=vs.110).aspx and then use White through obtained handles.

Comment: Seems that window spawned not by the process but by its child process can cause such issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532641/teststack-white-get-the-main-window-after-the-login-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that CCleaner is visible as WIN32 app. So `GetWindow()` doesn't work. You can try this code:

```cs
public void CCleanerSample()
{        
    var application = Application.AttachOrLaunch(new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe"));
    AutomationElement ccleanerAutomationElement = null;
    Console.Write("Waiting till WIN32 app is launching");
    while (ccleanerAutomationElement == null)
    {
        ccleanerAutomationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Piriform CCleaner"));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Write(".");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" Done");
    var mainWindow = new Win32Window(ccleanerAutomationElement, WindowFactory.Desktop, InitializeOption.NoCache,
        new WindowSession(application.ApplicationSession, InitializeOption.NoCache));
}
```